# Linked list c++ print only 1 node

Tags: c++, function

I have a simple linked list which seems to work fine, but I have a question. How can I print only the last node? I have a function which prints the full list

```
void printList()
{
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        cout << curr->data;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

And heres how i tried to do it but i failed

```
void printNode()
{
    curr = head;
    cout << curr->data;
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

Comment: Find the last node and print it.

Comment: Your implementation tells me your only trying to print the head node, think about exactly what say you are trying to do, if you are trying to print the last one... wouldn't it make sense to loop through until you are on the last node?

Comment: Many linked list implementations keep a pointer to both head and tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you Need to find the last node and then you Need to print it. It could look something like this:

```
void printList()
{
    curr = head;

    //if curr->next is NULL, we know that curr must be the last element
    while(curr != NULL && curr->next != null)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    cout << curr->data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like i wanted it to work. Really appreciate it

Comment: I think curr should be a temporary (local to the method) variable.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "head" is accessible by the method without needing to be sent as an argument, try this:

```
void printNode()
{
    if(!head) {
        cout<<"empty list"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    listNode* curr = head;
    while(curr->next) curr = curr->next; // Iterate to the last node

    cout << curr->data;
}
```

Comment: so we print list is empty, and still dereference head?

Comment: @Eddge, good catch! Thank you.

Comment: My only other comment would be based off of the implemetation mentioned above your head variable could cause some conflicts, since it isn't obvious if your using a passed in head, or if you are using the head in the class.

Comment: Yea, thats why its just my other comment would be, we don't know the full implementation of his class, or anything, so it would be really hard to tailor an answer to his specific needs.

Comment: You have a good point. It may be safer to assume that head is in class scope, so I just changed the function argument. The new method fits the original problem little better I believe.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print only the last node you have to scan the whole list until the `curr->next` is null, so you finally reach the last one. It could be easily implemented with a while loop that check every time if `curr->next != null`. After the loop, `curr` will point to the last element.